# Why isn't MSVC allocating a 32 byte shadow space in the generated assembly code?

Tags: c, assembly, visual-c++, x86-64, masm

I tried to see how MSVC allocates its 32 bytes of shadow space, but it seems like it only allocates 8 bytes shadow space.

```c
// Test.c
int main() {int var1 = 1;}
```

The program above results in the following .asm file:

```
var1$ = 0

main    PROC
; Test.c
    sub rsp, 24                    ; allocates 24 bytes
    mov DWORD PTR var1$[rsp], 1
    xor eax, eax
    add rsp, 24
    ret 0
main    ENDP
```

It only allocates 24 bytes. It allocates the same amount when I declare 4 variables, and since each variable is 4 bytes it must mean that 16 bytes of the 24 bytes are used for the declared variables, leaving 8 bytes for the shadow space.
Only when declaring 5 variables does it then allocate 40 bytes of shadow space. Why does it only allocate 8 bytes of shadow space?
I compiled the program using the command `CL Test.c /Fa`

Comment: I think you forgot to count the return address pushed by the code that calls `main`, which means the stack pointer is _misaligned_ by 8 bytes on entry to main.

Comment: That explains it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Subtracting 24 from *RSP* here doesn't have anything to do with shadow space. Shadow space only applies if `main` were to call some other 64-bit Microsoft ABI compliant function. Your `main` function is a leaf function (it doesn't call anything else) so it isn't required to allocate extra space for the shadow space. If you modified `main` to call something in the *C/C++* library or the WinAPI you'd find extra space would be added for the shadow space to make such a call.

Given that your function is dealing with 32-bit values (and no arrays) and doesn't call anything else I see no reason why it needs to align to a 16 byte boundary or add the extra padding, but that is what it appears to be doing. The return address on the stack misaligns the stack by 8. Subtracting 24 aligns it on a 16 byte boundary with padding after the variables.

This is likely a result of code generation inefficiencies when not compiling with any optimizations (like `/O1`, `/O2` etc) or the compiler padding local variable space to a preferred amount. In theory it didn't have to allocate any stack space in this case. It could have reused the shadow space above the return address that would have been allocated for the `main` function by the *C/C++* startup code.

Note: With optimizations the code would be eliminated altogether unless you made `var1` a `volatile` variable. The compiler should recognize the code you wrote doesn't do anything besides return back to the caller.

---

The following example calls `ExitProcess`to show shadow space is added; reuse of the shadow space allocated by the *C/C++* startup code that called `main` for local variables; and using some stack space for the variable it couldn't fit in the shadow space. As a WinAPI called `ExitProcess` needs to have the 32 bytes of shadow space allocated before making a call to it. If you remove it from this example the compiler will not allocate extra space for it.

**test.c**

```
// Test.c

// Get prototype for ExitProcess
#include <windows.h>

int main() 
{
    volatile int var1 = 1;
    volatile int var2 = 2;
    volatile int var3 = 3;
    volatile int var4 = 4;
    volatile int var5 = 5;

    // Since this is a WinAPI call it needs shadow space allocated
    ExitProcess(var1+var2+var3+var4+var5);

    // We won't get this far
    return 0;
}
```

If you compile this with [`/O2` optimizations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/o1-o2-minimize-size-maximize-speed?view=vs-2019) for maximum speed using `CL Test.c /Fa /O2` you would probably see something *similar* to:

```
var1$ = 32
var5$ = 64
var4$ = 72
var3$ = 80
var2$ = 88

main    PROC
    sub rsp, 56                 ; 00000038H
    mov DWORD PTR var1$[rsp], 1
    mov DWORD PTR var2$[rsp], 2
    mov DWORD PTR var3$[rsp], 3
    mov DWORD PTR var4$[rsp], 4
    mov DWORD PTR var5$[rsp], 5

    mov edx, DWORD PTR var5$[rsp]
    mov eax, DWORD PTR var4$[rsp]
    add edx, eax
    mov ecx, DWORD PTR var3$[rsp]
    add ecx, edx
    mov edx, DWORD PTR var2$[rsp]
    add edx, ecx
    mov ecx, DWORD PTR var1$[rsp]
    add ecx, edx

    call    QWORD PTR __imp_ExitProcess
    int 3
main    ENDP
```

`var1` has an offset of 32 from *RSP* because the shadow space is the first 32 bytes starting at *RSP* to make the call to `ExitProcess`. The other variables `var2`, `var3`, `var4` and `var5` all start at an offset >= 64. The compiler generated an adjustment of 56 to *RSP*. The return address is at *RSP+56* and `main` has shadow space at *RSP+64* to *RSP+96*, thus `var2` to `var5` were placed in the shadow space allocated for `main`.